# Link adb path from resource to execute shell commands in Java application

Tags: java, android, shell, intellij-idea, adb

I'm looking for a way to run adb commands directly from a java application. While search on Stack Overflow I found the following solution for running shell commands,

```
public class Utils {
    private static final String[] WIN_RUNTIME = {"cmd.exe", "/C"};
    private static final String[] OS_LINUX_RUNTIME = {"/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"};

    private Utils() {
    }

    private static <T> T[] concat(T[] first, T[] second) {
        T[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, first.length + second.length);
        System.arraycopy(second, 0, result, first.length, second.length);
        return result;
    }

    public static List<String> runProcess(boolean isWin, String... command) {
        System.out.print("command to run: ");
        for (String s : command) {
            System.out.print(s);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        String[] allCommand = null;
        try {
            if (isWin) {
                allCommand = concat(WIN_RUNTIME, command);
            } else {
                allCommand = concat(OS_LINUX_RUNTIME, command);
            }
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(allCommand);
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process p = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String _temp = null;
            List<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();
            while ((_temp = in.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println("temp line: " + _temp);
                line.add(_temp);
            }
            System.out.println("result after command: " + line);
            return line;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, however I couldn't find a solution to add the adb.exe path into the shell commands so that I can execute adb commands.

My project structure is given below,

[image]

I'm trying to append the adb path along with the system default shell path using the following way,

```
Utils.runProcess(true, "/resources/adb.exe devices");
```

Is there any way to append the adb.exe path from resources into the shell command?

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path to `adb.exe` that way you don't need to add it to `%PATH%`.

eg. If you open `cmd` and run `C:\...\adb.exe devices` it will work

Alternatively execute this command in the shell to set your path,

```
setx path "%path%;C:\..."
```

**Edit:** Add the `adb.exe` in your `resources` folder in the same package as your calling class. Then load it and write it to another location that you happen to know (or generate a path relative to where your jar is located eg.`System.getProperty("user.dir"`);
)

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("adb.exe").getFile());
// now copy this file to a location you already know eg. C:\...\temp\adb.exe
```

And then invoke `adb.exe` with the path that you have

Comment: Actually I want to embed the adb files inside the jar file, So that the application could be launch without pre-saved sdk tools. Right now, I can't link the adb path from the java application's resource folder.

Comment: You can't easily do that. What I'd suggest doing is add it to your resources, then write it into a directory on the local system by reading from the classpath and then pass that path. I will add some sample code